# glutLookAt misunderstanding

Tags: opengl, glulookat

Lets say I do have the following set up :

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-10, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1,0);  glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-10, 0, 5);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(10, 0, 5);
glEnd();
```

And I do the following

```
gluLookAt(0,0,10, 0,5,0, 0,1,0);
```

I should end up with a "virtual world" like the one below, right ?

[image]

For a strange reason, nothing appears on screen and I can't figure out why. Any idea ?

Comment: That all looks correct. The fault is somewhere else.

Comment: Well I just figured out what the problem was (It was related to a moving function wich was putting me way off rendered scene)...
Thanks for reassuring me on the understanding of glutlookat anyway, I stopped looking to that direction !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you inverted Y axis and Z axis in your triangles. You probably wanted to write this:

```
glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex3f(-10, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1,0);  glVertex3f(10, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex3f(-10, 5, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex3f(10, 5, 0);
```

This corresponds better to the figure you attached to your question.

Comment: You are indeed right ... Was a little bit tired yesterday and it ended up working, but with some tweeking, and the tweek was actually involving Y / Z axis. I modified back to my previous version this morning with your answer included and it worked right away.
I am still struggling with the XYZ usage in games with Y being commonly the "up" vector.